# Zend framework 2 : Add different authentication adapter for two different modules

Tags: events, authentication, routes, zend-framework2, collision

I have two different modules. Now I need to add different authentication mechanism for both modules.

So I added event code first module's Module.php's onBootstrap method

```
$listener = $serviceManager->get('First\Service\AuthListener');
$listener->setAdapter($serviceManager->get('First\Service\BasicAuthAdapter'));
$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, $listener, 0);
```

and in second module's Module.php's onBootstrap method

```
$listener = $serviceManager->get('Second\Service\AuthListener');
$listener->setAdapter($serviceManager->get('Second\Service\AdvAuthAdapter'));
$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, $listener, 0);
```

Now if I disable one of modules, functionality working fine and request properly authenticated. While enabling both module do some kind of overlapping So even required module properly authenticated, But other module event code also got executed and system give not authenticated error.

I am thinking this due to event handler code in both module.php is executed without take care of requested module url.

I can verify with requested route pattern before authentication, But that is look like a hack instead of good solution.

If better solution exists for handling this issue ?

UPDATE : 
My AuthListener Code :

```
namespace First\Service;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class AuthListener
{
    protected $adapter;

    public function setAdapter(AdapterInterface $adapter)
    {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
    }

    public function __invoke(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $result = $this->adapter->authenticate();

        if (!$result->isValid()) {

            $response = $event->getResponse();

            // Set some response content
            $response->setStatusCode(401);

            $routeMatch = $event->getRouteMatch();
            $routeMatch->setParam('controller', 'First\Controller\Error');
            $routeMatch->setParam('action', 'Auth');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good way to make module specific bootstrap - to use `SharedManager`:

```
$e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()
  ->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function(MvcEvent $e) {

     // This code will be executed for all controllers in current __NAMESPACE__

}, 100);
```

[Here](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/05/12/understanding-the-zend-framework-2-event-manager/) is a good article to understand difference between `EventManager` and `SharedEventManager`

There is no additional info about listeners in the question, but I try to guess:

- If you use as listener some `callable` class - it's ok, just replace `function() { }` by your `$listener`.
- If you use as listener some class, that implements
  `ListenerAggregateInterface`, you should convert listeners to
  `SharedListenerAggregateInterface` and use method `attachAggregate`
  instead of `attach`

I hope it helps!

Comment: As to your update: yes, your `AuthListener` is callable, so you can write just `$e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()
  ->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', $listener)`

Comment: Not working, While no errors generated. But listener class's __invoke not executing now.

Comment: I've checked it again - it should work. Did you try to write `exit('it works');` at the beginning of `__invoke()` to be sure, that callback executed? Did you change `MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE` (in your code) to `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH` (in my code)? And check your `Module.php` namespace and `Controller` namespace - they should have equal first part (`First` or `Second` in your case).