# Zf2 : Controller forwarding/calling generate 404 Error

Tags: rest, authentication, zend-framework2, phpunit

I am implementing separate auth solution for two different modules described in another question by me.

[Zend framework 2 : Add different authentication adapter for two different modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146916/zend-framework-2-add-different-authentication-adapter-for-two-different-module/29241777)

Now in AuthListener file I write code for forward/call to an different controller/action if authentication failed. That is

```
    $result = $this->adapter->authenticate();

    if (!$result->isValid()) {

        $response = $event->getResponse();

        // Set some response content
        $response->setStatusCode(401);

        $routeMatch = $event->getRouteMatch();
        $routeMatch->setParam('controller', 'First\Controller\Error');
        $routeMatch->setParam('action', 'Auth');
    }
```

Now I am getting 404 error - "The requested controller was unable to dispatch the request". First I think I do not added route for Error/Auth, but then I verified it got 404 for all other controller/action too. All are directly accessible through their respective route. But forwarding resulting in 404 error.  One important thing - I sending authentication request through phpunit to make unit test cases.

UPDATE : route details :

```
'routes' => array(
    'rest' => array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/rest[/:id]',
            'constraints' => array(
                'id'     => '[0-9]+',
            ),
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'First\Controller\Index'
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'error' => array(
        'type'    => 'segment',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/rest-error/[/:action][/:id]',
            'constraints' => array(
                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                'id'     => '[0-9]+',
            ),
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'First\Controller\Error',
                'action'     => 'auth',
            ),
        ),
    )
),

'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'First\Controller\Auth' => 'First\Controller\AuthController',
        'First\Controller\Error' => 'First\Controller\ErrorController'
    ),
),
```

Module.php

```
$listener = $serviceManager->get('First\Service\AuthListener');
$listener->setAdapter($serviceManager->get('Rest\Service\BasicAuthAdapter'));
$eventManager->getSharedManager()->attach('First', 'dispatch', $listener, 100);
```

I also tried to use forward instead of above solutio, But that gives error for circular forward `Circular forwarding detected: greater than 10 nested forwards`. I think event called when forward called.

Comment: My guess would be that the controller `First\Controller\Error` doesn't exist...

Comment: @Wilt It exists, Error comes for other controller too like Application\Controller\Index which is default controller. While route works perfectly.

Comment: show your routes for that controller

Comment: @Xerkus, I updated the router in question, However this should not be requirement as I did not use route. I transfer request to other controller using  setParam

Comment: Is your listener connected to `MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE`? Can you show how you connect your listener to an event...?

Comment: @Wilt added code. I am using now dispatch instead of route event as fix in linked question.

Answer (score 0):

try to call your action like that :
$routeMatch->setParam('action', 'auth');

Comment: your action auth is in the controller : 'First\Controller\Error' and not  'First\Controller\Auth'?

Comment: Yes my action is in First\Controller\Error . First\Controller\Auth is a REST Controller while  First\Controller\Error is normal controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might occure because you are listening to `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH`. In your listener you set new `controller` and `action` variables for `RouteMatch` but since you are already passed the route event changing those parameters will not have any effect.

You should listen to `MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE` instead and then it will probably work.

Comment: Can not, as other issue described in linked question is fixed by change route  -> dispatch event.  Can not revert now.